# Onesignal errors in flutter: requires a placeholder substitution but no value for

Tags: android, flutter-dependencies

Getting the following error when building APK (Flutter).

I added my Onesignal App ID even thou I'm not currently making use of it.
Someone mentioned that my Onesignal SDK is not properly installed: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup
but I don't think that's it.

Fluxstore App

Thanks!

```
C:\fluxstore\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\release\out\AndroidManifest.xml:328:13-48 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#onesignal_app_id@value at AndroidManifest.xml:328:13-48 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_app_id> is provided.
C:\fluxstore\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\release\out\AndroidManifest.xml:331:13-67 Error:
        Attribute meta-data#onesignal_google_project_number@value at AndroidManifest.xml:331:13-67 requires a placeholder substitution but no value for <onesignal_google_project_number> is provided.
C:\fluxstore\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\release\out\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting
```

**This is my Android Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.website.store">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Website"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://website.co.za" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="website.co.za" />
                <data  android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

         <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo" />
        <!-- Set color used with incoming notification messages. This is used when no color is set for the incoming
            notification message. See README(https://googl/6BKBk7) for more. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/notiColor" />

        <!-- Google map and Admod setup -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/api_key"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_api"/>

        <!-- Facebook Login configuration -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help...

Try going to your

> android/app/build.gradle

Find `defaultConfig` and add the following piece of code:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
            onesignal_app_id: 'ONE SIGNAL APP ID',
            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
            onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.app.android"
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        onesignal_app_id: 'ONE SIGNAL APP ID HERE',
        // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
        onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
    ]
}
```

Your Onesignal Google project number is your Firebase Sender ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
}
...
```

}

You can then insert one of the placeholders into the manifest file as an attribute value like this:

```
<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="${hostName}" ... />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

For more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#groovy